# Find and delete header columns without a certain word.

Tags: excel, vba

I need to:
 1. Find a column containing the word 'target' in header. (from the range P1 to QI1 )
 2. Delete all other column without 'target' in its header.

Code:

```
Sub Cleanup()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet.Range("P1:QI1")
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("P1:QI1").Find(What:="target", _
            LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        Do While Not rng Is Nothing
            rng.EntireColumn.Delete
            Set rng = .FindNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

the code above is deleting all the column with the word 'target'. i would like it the other way around. i need to keep those columns.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TESTED - enjoy :)

```
Sub test()
Dim erange As Range
Dim str As String
    For Each erange In Range("A1:E1")
      If not erange.Value = "Target" Then
      '  If InStr(erange.Value, "Target") <> 0 Then
            If str <> "" Then
                str = str & "," & erange.EntireColumn.Address
            Else
                str = erange.EntireColumn.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next erange
str = Replace(str, "$", "")
' Delete columns in single shot
Range(str).Delete
End Sub
```